# Is it more efficient to separate my widgets using a method or a separate class which extends Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been tasked with optimizing certain aspects of an app I'm developing, and after doing some research, I have found this [article](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-flutter-app./) saying that separating widgets using methods is an inefficient way of handling things.

The author says that it's much better to create separate classes with these widgets that extend a Stateless Widget.

Is this really how it's supposed to be, and why so?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That article you linked explains everything that you're asking. It has to do with the number of rebuilds. The idea is that we always want to minimize the amount of rebuilds whenever possible for performance reasons. One way to achieve that is to refactor into stateless widgets vs in class methods.

Especially when you're able to use a const constructor in your stateless widget, which build only once, the amount of rebuilds you save can really add up.

Using a [stricter lint package](https://pub.dev/packages/lint) can help because will tell you any time you're not using a const constructor when you should be.

Comment: Yeah, it does explain it pretty well, but i just wanted to make sure, since I don't see it very often. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you should separate your widgets as much as possible.

1. Wrap them under new widgets and extend necessary Stateless or Statefullwidget.
2. use the refactor in VsCode very useful!

This optimizes the code as well as makes code more high quality and maintainable.
Otherwise will turn into a spaghetti code
Monolithic code always harder to maintain.